# Crash when firebase photo is missing

Tags: swift

I know this...
My app crashes because it finds a nil value from Firebase. While there is a default image in Xcode, a new user has no data yet in firebase and so unwrapping the nil value results in an inevitable crash. How can I display the default profile image until a new user selects one of their own?

func setupProfile(){

```
    profile_image.layer.cornerRadius = profile_image.frame.size.width/2
    profile_image.clipsToBounds = true
    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{
        databaseRef.child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            {
                self.usernameLabel.text = dict["username"] as? String
                if let profileImageURL = dict["pic"] as? String

                {
                    let url = URL(string: profileImageURL)
                    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                        if error != nil{
                            print(error!)
                            return
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.profile_image?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        }
                    }).resume()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you tried using method

```
if snapshot.exists(){
  /// Code when snapshot returns a Value
}
else{
  /// Snapshot has no value 
  /// Here is the crash point 
  /// dont run other operations 
}
```

Second options as

```
databaseRef.child("Events").observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.hasChild(/// Comparison value if you have , Like checking for a Value to verify snapshot is not empty)
            {
                 /// Value found /// Run operations
            }
            else{
                 /// Value not found 
             }

})
```

Comment: This really helps.  I am new to coding so I ran into a trouble with this because my snapshot contains two values that exist and one that does not so I wasn't sure how to keep the name value but ignore the nil "pic" value with this method (which I will definitely use in a completely different function). But it did lead me to simple if-else statement which solved the problem and the view controller is working!

Comment: Glad this helped you, Happy coding